# File size increases when converting an html file to adobe pdf using google apps script

Tags: html, pdf, google-apps-script

For some reason, when converting an HTML file to a PDF in Google Apps Script, the file size of the PDF ends up being way bigger than the original HTML file.

The code I used to run the test is below:

```
function convertHTMLtoPDF() {
// convert a specific message with an attached HTML file to PDF,
// and save it to the root directory of Google Drive
  var threads = GmailApp.search('subject:(Sample HTML)');
  var message = threads[0].getMessages()[0];

  var attachmentName = message.getAttachments()[0].getName();

  var attachment = message.getAttachments()[0].getAs("application/pdf");
  DriveApp.createFile(attachment).setName(attachmentName);

}
```

NOTE: You just need to take the sample HTML file I'm sharing below, attach it to an email with the subject: Sample HTML, and send it to yourself to allow the script to find it.

The [sample HTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LEHSedHuTxblZFV0o5bmxNdW8/view?usp=sharing) file I was converting is 133 KB. The converted    is 10 MB after the script is run.

My test results are as follows:

- Converting the sample.html file with Google Apps Script causes the 133 KB HTML file to become a 10 MB PDF.
- Converting the sample.html file with Adobe Acrobat XI Pro causes the 133 KB HTML file to become a 151 KB PDF.

Does anyone know why the file size of the PDF that is converted through Google Apps Script is so much bigger than when converting with Adobe? Is there a way to reduce the file size?

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: If you want to see the results of the conversion through Google Apps Script, the sample PDF file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7LEHSedHuTxLUlKRnlWQ05sZWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I confirmed that the size became larger(10 MB). I think this is natural because PDF file is always large compared to the original type of the file. You can find many reasons in the internet that can explain that. One example is [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/230496/why-are-pdf-files-generated-by-microsoft-word-so-large/).

To confirm that, I used this [script](https://ctrlq.org/code/19960-convert-html-to-pdf) to confirm that size.

```
function htmlToPDF() {

  var html = "YOUR HTML CODE";

  var blob = Utilities.newBlob(html, "text/html", "text.html");
  var pdf = blob.getAs("application/pdf");

  DriveApp.createFile(pdf).setName("text.pdf");

  MailApp.sendEmail("sample@email.org", "PDF File", "", 
     {htmlBody: html, attachments: pdf});

}
```

And I also get 10MB size from this code.

Comment: "this is natural because PDF file is always large compared to the original type of the file" - Utter nonsense. PDFs can use flate/deflate compression and actually be many times smaller than the same text held in a .txt file.

Comment: I agree, I think this is a bug in Google Apps Script because there is no good reason why the file size would be so much bigger when converting through Apps Script. Does anyone else have any idea how to fix this or should I be submitting this a bug to Google?

Comment: If you submit a bug report to the Google, can you please link here the bug ticket that you filed.

Comment: I have submitted this as a Google Apps Script bug. The issue number is 6312 and can be found here: https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6312