# Export Sheet via Apps Script as PDF (something change now no more searchable and much bigger file size)

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google Sheets for a few years now. I have several bigger sheets running. One of these creates via an apps script a PDF doc out of one single sheet. The code is running well since over three years now. But since a few days, the created PDF files are no more searchable and the file size of those single PDF files increases from about 150kb to 2MB (2 DIN A4 pages) and the other ones from about 1.5MB to over 12MB (8 DIN A4 pages).

Below is the part of the code, how I create the PDF file. The gid is just an example.

```
var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ssID+"/export"+
                                                    "?format=pdf&"+
                                                    "gid=1234567890&"+
                                                    "size=A4&"+
                                                    "fzr=true&"+
                                                    "portrait=true&"+
                                                    "fitw=false&"+
                                                    "gridlines=false&"+
                                                    "printtitle=false&"+
                                                    "sheetnames=false&"+
                                                    "pagenum=CENTER&"+
                                                    "top_margin=0.5&"+
                                                    "left_margin=0.8&"+
                                                    "right_margin=0.5&"+
                                                    "bottom_margin=0.8&"+
                                                    "attachment=true";
var blob = pdf.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(namearchive + '.pdf');
var file = foldersave.createFile(blob);
```

Does anyone have any idea, why this now changed? Has Google changed something in the app?

The only thing I found was perhaps this bug related to here, but not sure if this is the same: [File size increases when converting an html file to adobe pdf using google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38753578/file-size-increases-when-converting-an-html-file-to-adobe-pdf-using-google-apps)

Would be very nice, if someone has an idea.
Many thanks.

Comment: Is there any difference between the structure / size of sheets you were exporting ebfore and the ones you are exporting now? Do the new sheets contain images, draphs, pivot tables?

Comment: no. all the same. I even tried with an older backup. But it is also the problem when I export the sheet via the normal menu (without script). So I think Google has changed here something

Comment: I see. In this case it is not an Apps Script specific question.

Comment: Is there any workaround to reduce the file size. And also perhaps to work with ocr and create a new file via script?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot I found now out, that the file size depends on the used font. The sheet was created with the font "Calibri". When I print one sheet e.g. the size is 1.3MB. When I change the font to "Arial" the font size is 53kb.